# Phalconphp OAuth2.0 Wrapper problems

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, iis-7.5, phalcon

I am trying to get this phalconphp OAuth2.0 wrapper working on my OAuth2.0 server.
The README of this repository is not very clear on how to use the namespaces.
I have followed the guide but I keep getting the following error :

```
  Fatal error: Class 'Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql\Client' 
not found in C:\localhost\oauth2-phalcon\public\index.php on line 56
```

Here is my index.php file :

```
<?php

require __DIR__."/../vendor/autoload.php";

// Setup IIS Rewrite Rules
// Enable the verbs GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
// Check URL Scan for dissallowed seperators eg ; : 

$config = new \Phalcon\Config([
    'database'    => [
        'oauth' => [
            'host'          => 'localhost\test',
            'port'          => 1433,
            'instance'      => 'INSTANCENAME',
            'username'      => 'test',
            'password'      => 'test',
            'dbname'        => 'oauth',                
            'pdoType'       => 'sqlsrv',
            'dialectClass'  => '\Twm\Db\Dialect\Mssql'            
        ],
    ],
    # ...

]);


# Register The Lib to the loader
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

$loader->registerNamespaces([
    "Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo"            => "../app/library/db/adapter/",
    "Twm\Db\Dialect"                => "../app/library/db/dialect/",
    "League"                        => "../vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/League/OAuth2/Server",    
    //"Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo" => "../Oauth2/Server/Storage/Pdo/Mysql",
    "Sum"                           =>  "../Oauth2/Server/Storage/Pdo/Mysql",
    //"Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql" => "../Oauth2/Server/Storage/Pdo/Mysql "
    # ...
])->register();

$app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro();

# set as service
$app->setService('oauth', function() use ($config) {    
    // HERE! We use our custom MSSQL Adapter
   //$oauthdb = new Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql($config->database->oauth->toArray());
    $oauthdb = new \Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql($config->database->oauth->toArray());    
    $server = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Authorization(        
        new \Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql\Client($oauthdb),
        new Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql\Session($oauthdb),
        new Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql\Scope($oauthdb)
        // new \Sum\Oauth2\Server\Client($oauthdb),
        //new \Sum\Oauth2\Server\Session($oauthdb),
        //new \Sum\Oauth2\Server\Scope($oauthdb)                            
    );
    # Not required as it called directly from original code
    # $request = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Util\Request();

    # add these 2 lines code if you want to use my own Request otherwise comment it
    $request = new \Sum\Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mysql\Request(); 
    $server->setRequest($request);

    $server->setAccessTokenTTL(86400);
    $server->addGrantType(new League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentials());
});

$app->get('/hello', function() use($world){
   $world = "world";
   echo "hello {$world}:)";   
});

$app->get('/access', function () use ($app) {
    try {
        $params = $app->oauth->getParam(array('client_id', 'client_secret'));
        echo json_encode(
            $app->oauth
                ->getGrantType('client_credentials')
                ->completeFlow($params)
        );
    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }
});

$app->handle();
//echo $app->handle()->getContent();
```

The project repository for the phalcon wrapper is here :
https://github.com/sumeko/phalcon-oauth2

I have contacted the author already but he is not replying to my emails.

I appreciate any help or advice, thanks.

**UPDATE**

So I solved my issue. Basically you need to have the standard OAuth2 library installed via composer and the phalconphp OAuth2 wrapper. 
That solved it :)

Comment: can you post your index.php file again? what that is working.

Comment: how didi you install phalconphp OAuth2 wrapper?

Comment: hi @pregmatch i just installed the phalcon wrapper using composer and made sure the paths are correct. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a long shot, but the problem might be with the autoloader that you are explicitly defining. If you use composer's autoload, you don't need to include `Sum` namespace in Phalcon's loader. Remove all vendor-specific paths from `$loader->registerNamespaces()` and only use `require __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php"` for that.

Also, it's often more convenient use composer's autoloader for your internal things too, e.g.:

```
{

    "require": {
        "phpunit/dbunit": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "…": "…"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "../src"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great tip! Thanks man, appreciate the advice. I succeeded and almost completed my API. Im just struggling my butt off getting the Password grant type to work on my OAuth2.0 server. I posted a question on stackoverflow but no answers yet :(

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my issue. Basically you need to have the standard OAuth2 library installed via composer and the phalconphp OAuth2 wrapper. That solved it :)